# Spiral print in OCaml

Tags: clojure, ocaml

There is the famous exercise to print a matrix (represented as vector of vectors) the spiral way and I am would like to do it in OCaml.

Given the the following matrix it should print 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

```
[ [1 2 3] 
  [8 9 4] 
  [7 6 5] ]
```

The elegant implementation adds the first sub-vector to the accumulator and calls the function recursively with the rotated remaining numbers.

The rotated remaining part looks the following after the first iteration

```
[ [4 5] 
  [9 6] 
  [8 7] ]
```

In Clojure I do the following to rotate the vectors:

```
(reverse (apply map vector [[8 9 4] [7 6 5]]))
([4 5] [9 6] [8 7])
```

I am wondering if there is something similar in OCaml. I found List.map but not sure about the rest. Should I just implement something that reads the last element from each sub-vector?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a possible implementation of the rotation function:

```
let rotate ll =
    let cons x y = x :: y in
    let init = List.map (fun _ -> []) (List.hd ll) in
    let rres = List.fold_right (List.map2 cons) ll init in
    List.rev rres
```

Here is an example session:

```
$ ocaml
        OCaml version 4.01.0

# #use "rot.ml";;
val rotate : 'a list list -> 'a list list = <fun>
# rotate [[8; 9; 4]; [7; 6; 5]];;
- : int list list = [[4; 5]; [9; 6]; [8; 7]]
```